# OPC not able to load file or assembly

Tags: c#, opc

I am working on a C# application that interfaces with a Siemens OPC Server housed on the same PC. I've tested the server with OPC Scout as well as the Kepware QuickClient for communication problems, and they both work fine.

When I try to connect to my software, however, it comes back with an error that happens on the .Connect() command:

> Could not load file or assembly 'OpcComRcw, Version 2.0.105.1,
>   Culture=neutral

There is another PC on a different site I have tested the software on, and it appears to connect with no problems. Any ideas as to what would cause the program to throw this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These assemblies are freely available from the OPC website or you can grab them from my [github repository](https://github.com/jdecuyper/OPC-HDA-Client/tree/master/OpcNetApi%20Assemblies) :)

Just copy OpcComRcw.dll to the application's folder or the computer´s [GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268342/what-is-the-gac-in-net).