# Reference dll in C:\Programs files without copy it

Tags: c#, dll, vsto

I have a vsto outlook that references my library *my.dll*. This dll reference a 3rd party *dummy.dll* in C:\Programs Files\company\dummy.dll

The objectif is if *dummy.dll* is changed, it will be independent with *my.dll*

In the project of *my.dll*:

If I set copy local to true, the *dummy.dll* is copied to the bin, that doesn’t like I expected because *my.dll* doesn’t know about the newer version of *dummy*

If I set copy local to false, an exception comes because file not found.

I found this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/837908/how-to-load-an-assembly-at-runtime-that-is-located-in-a-folder-that-is) of Microsoft and others posts in SO, they talks about GAC, .config or  AssemblyResolvebut I think it’s not like my situation because it’s a vsto.

How can I use dummy.dll in c:\program files without copying it?

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is in a subdirectory of your application, you can tell .NET to bind to it using the [probing path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) portion of the application's configuration.

If the DLL is in a directory that is not a subdirectory of your application, you will have to put it in the [global assembly cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268342/what-is-the-gac-in-net). This is [not usually recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538710/why-should-i-not-use-the-gac).

The simplest approach though is to copy the file. That is how this sort of thing is commonly handled. Before .NET, DLLs could be anywhere, but that sort of arrangement often resulted in what was called [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). Having a private copy of the DLL eases many deployment concerns and the disk space usage should not be an issue.

Comment: After thinking about your answer and some research, I think copy file is correct. I make some tests and tell you later

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the exe.config option from that article. We do this all of the time to reference third party application dlls that are in that party's directories.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly2" publicKeyToken="307041694a995978"/>
            <codeBase version="1.0.1524.23149" href="C:\Myassemblies\MyAssembly2.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```